# Is it possible to run ios apps developed using react-native in linux to real iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, linux, react-native, react-native-ios

I am having a **react-native app**. I would like to generate an iOS app from my linux/windows machine. Is it possbile? Some friends has suggested me about BuddyBuild. is there any alternative solutions for me?? I have the following physical devices

1. Laptop running windows & linux (running node.js,python,java,npm,and lot more)
2. iPhone 5S
3. Internet Connection

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: yes @FunkSoulNinja

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try Expo. It's built on top of React Native and it makes developing a lot easier because you can see what you code instantly on a real phone. You can send links to people or even use a QR code to share your projects as you work on them.

[Expo](https://expo.io/)

Comment: Thank you @FunkSoulNinja. Yeah Expo sounds good over RN. Is it possible for me to generate an ipa file for my iPhone using Expo or it can directly run on my iOS device???

Comment: @ThomasEaso. With Expo you download an app (also called Expo) from app store onto your smartphone and send a code that the desktop Expo client has to your phone (or a QR code) to connect to it.

You can also build a standalone file for either iOS or Android with Expo. The documentation for that can be found here [Build Standalone Apps](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v17.0.0/guides/building-standalone-apps.html)